# Awesomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use the following simple and basic request of Awesomplete plugin

```
<label style="display: inline-block; margin-left:20px;">Pays:</label>
       <input class="awesomplete" id="upays" type="text" size="40"
         data-list="Allemagne,Austria,Bulgaria,Belgium,Spain,Sweden />
```

to gather a country name.

The code is a part of a modal windows ( simpleModal plugin ).

So, the first time I call the modal windows, the Awesome plugin works fine, but when I call it the second time ( in the same script ) Awesomplete doesnt work. It's like a no call of the plugin?
How to refresh/react the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You miss quote in your country list

```
<label style="display: inline-block; margin-left:20px;">Pays:</label>
<input class="awesomplete" id="upays" type="text" size="40" data-list="Allemagne,Austria,Bulgaria,Belgium,Spain,Sweden" />
```

or have you try the list option

```
<input class="awesomplete" id="upays" type="text" size="40"  list="theList" />
<datalist id="theList">
    <option>Allemagne</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Bulgaria</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
    <option>Spain</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks. The miss quote is due to a bad copy/paste. The datalist as proposal doesnt wok even the first time. I think the probleme is coming from th imbrication of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After some lecture I've found the following solution.

Before to recall the modal form you need to refreh the Awesomplete plugin

new Awesomplete(upays);             // refresh/reactive awesomplete plugin

$('#ufav-modal-content').modal({ minHeight:350, minWidth: 500 });     // display modal frame

Hope to be useful